# The blog editor room has been frozen – now what?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog, chat

Our [blog editor room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/356) has been frozen due to inactivity. It's now been more than two weeks that someone posted in it. Our last blog entry is almost two months old.

This *is* a bit sad.

We've had a couple of people interested in writing for the blog. We invited them to just submit *anything*, but not a single one actually sent us a draft, if I'm not mistaken. The Trello board has quite a few ideas listed, and we also have a couple of existing drafts to work with.

But where do we go from here? How do we resurrect the blog? Any ideas?

<sub>… and before I repeat myself: [How can we promote the blog?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3766/48078)</sub>

Comment: I've unfrozen it, but the question's still valid.

Comment: Thanks, yeah… that's merely curing the symptom.

Comment: For those who missed it or are new here: [slhck's brilliant idea of an integrated blogging platform on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy)

Comment: Just to repeat myself: I wish I knew...

Comment: Well, in the short time that I've been here, I've gone from wanting to contribute as a user, to wanting to contribute MORE as a user, to being pissed when people comment my answers are too long, to being disillusioned with the community as a whole.  So, if people don't want to contribute to writing blog posts, I'm not surprised.

Comment: @BonGart: If people do that it is because the lack of a summary, not because of the length of an answer. ALso, blog posts don't have to be long. It's a perceived high barrier that doesn't have to be so; writing long blog posts each time, is what makes some of us exhausted.